# english testcase parser

Tags: c#

I need to make a winforms desktop application with a text box where in user (tester) will copy his script like:

```
ADD NEW PRODUCT "chair-$50" //should invoke AddProduct(name,price) c# method
REMOVE PRODUCT "table" //should invoke RemoveProduct(name) c# method
```

I do not want to write parser of my own. Is there any simple framework for parsing english test case to execute methods?

Few I encountered are SpecFlow & Cucumber, but can I use them just for parsing purpose within my application without using any testing tool like NUnit etc.

What are best & easiest options? Can I use specflow for this?

Comment: Is it always `command` `entity` `value[s]` ?

Comment: Does Your commands always have only one param or it could be several parameters?

Comment: It can have different params... In real case My test case would be like "SEND xyz_command TO ipAddress MACaddress WITH DELAY 10seconds .... something like this will be in 1 line of testcase. there will be multiple such different  lines.

Comment: Given how simple this is, you are better off just writing your own surely? Can't you write the tests in C#, and then load a testcase assembly into your process/call its method?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got just a few methods you want to expose this way, take input lines and parse them.  You can do it in 2 lines for each method.  (Code in Java, don't know C#)

```
 while(true){
      String s = keyboard.nextLine();//get the user input
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
      String firstToken = st.nextToken();
      if(firstToken.equals("add"))
           add(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
      else if(firstToken.equals("remove"))
           remove(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Comment: There are actually 19-20 methods.. What I illustrated is very simplified example. Even I am tempted to write my own parser but it may get out of control from maintainability perspective, hence want to use some existing framework. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a line based command language as you show you can do it with a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) based parser writenn by your own. 
Then you can use some naming convention between the line command, ie:
ADD NEW PRODUCT -> Pascalize -> AddNewProduct() in your class behind, so it would be easy to extend the language to other operations. Using Convert.ChangeType to inject the parameter with the expected type of the function would be an idea too... and so on

Comment: RegEx is the keyword which is making me attract towards specflow. Specflow just allows to put an attribute over method with RegEx and is automatically invoked by NUnit when a test case line matches that RegEx. However, in all examples this happens automatically when using a Testing tool like NUnit. In my custom application, how can I emulate this with my code. Probably, if Specflow is not helpful I will go with your way only

Comment: it is not difficult: read the doc I sent and I'm sure you got how to doit in minutes ( even digging inside some IoC code woul help you in the passing parameyter strategy )

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would prefer write simple framework consisting of three parts:

1) Command and arguments parser
2) Settings block, which defines command to class method mapping
3) Executor block, it executes class methods and passes params according to settings